# Why are quadrants defined the way they are?

Tags: soft-question

I was thinking about planes and things, and suddenly wondered why quadrants are defined the way they are, the first on the top-right, and so on.
I wonder if this gives us any benefit, or if any historical/mathematical reasons behind it exist. 
Thank you! (and sorry for my bad English)

Comment: They are numbered the order you encounter them when you move in the direction angles increase. There is nothing more.

Comment: Most-likely because of our convention to use counter-clockwise as positive orientation, and the fact that the positive $x$-axis is where it is.

Comment: For curiosity, may I add that in Star Trek the four quadrants of the Milky Way galaxy, when viewed in a counter-clockwise sequence, are labelled as: Alpha, Beta, Delta, Gamma.

Comment: **Hint:** As *n* takes the values $0,1,2,3,4,\ldots$ plot $i^n$ on the complex plane, and see what happens... :-$)$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ultimately it's just a convention, and it could equally well have been different. But there are some other conventions it ought to align with (so they would possibly also have to change to make everything fit together):

- As Yagna Patel points out, quadrant numbering is intimately connected with the *standard parameterization of the unit circle*. Change one and you'll have to change the other to fit (if you don't want to go crazy).
- In the *complex plane*, the standard parameterization of the unit circle ought to align with $t\mapsto e^{it}$, so once we have decided how to parameterize the circle, we get the position and orientation of both the real and imaginary axis.
- Going back to *two-dimensional coordinate geometry*, we'll want to parameterize the unit circle such that $t=0$ is at the intersection of one of the axes. And it's also somewhat easier to think about things if a small *positive* $t$ corresponds to the quadrant where both coordinates are positive, so that has to be the first quadrant.
- The horizontal axis could be either the first or second coordinate in a coordinate pair -- but it should grow from left to right because that is the reading direction in the language the trendsetting mathematicians communicate in.
- Finally, we can number the quadrants either 1,2,3,4 or 0,1,2,3 without much influence on other conventions.

How these considerations work out is that as long as our basic coordinate system has the axes growing towards the right and up, there are two orderings of the quadrants that make things fit together, namely `NE NW SW SE` and `NE SE SW NW`. The first of this is the convention pure mathematics uses, the second would align with the scale for compass directions used in practical (air/sea) navigation. (It's a minor nuisance that these conventions are different, but neither is realistically changeable).

If we also consider systems where the vertical axis grows downwards (which is quite common in computer graphics, ultimately because that's the direction line numbers grow in in text), we get the possibilities `SE SW NW NE` and `SE NE NW SW`.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that the quadrants are numbered in the order an angle in standard position passes through them as the angle  increases - that is, counterclockwise starting at the x axis. Additionally, because that's the direction that the point $(\cos x, \sin x)$ goes when $x$ goes from $0 \text{ to } 2\pi$ (it makes a circle).

Answer (score 1):

I too asked this question for many years. Why are the quadrants numbered counterclockwise starting with top right quadrant as the first?

[image of coordinate plane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdV5V.png)

I finally gained some perspective when I started watching the night sky through a telescope and began tracking the motion of celestial objects.

Where do the sun and moon rise? where do they set?

Since many of our first mathematicians were astronomers and much of math was being used to track the motion of celestial bodies it makes sense that the natural rotation about the origin be defined counterclockwise, for that is the motion we observe in the night sky. I coupled this observation with the fact that the first person to bridge the gap between Algebra and Geometry was René Descartes when he invented the Cartesian Plane, now called the coordinate plane, and thus, all mathematics emanating from this point in history used Descartes' method for plotting functions and rotations.

Let me know what you think of this proposed explanation.

[image of sun and earth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbTSE.jpg)

[My Webpage](http://www.mrhudak.com)

[My YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/c/mrhudak)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).